# Accessing Visio UML Model Data from a .vxd file

Tags: uml, visio

**Goal:** 
Create UML drawings in Visio and then extract all of the content for use in other contexts.

**Path attempted:** 
I thought this would be easy to reverse engineer.  I saved a simple UML activity diagram as a .vxd file, read the .vxd into a Python elementtree and scoured the tree for evidence of my drawing.

I was able to locate the shapes easily enough but none the properties I entered were observable.  For example, I labeled the name of the 'intial state' shape 'zzzzname'.  The string 'zzzz' appears nowhere in the .vdx file.

There is one element with binary data (63k characters) tagged 'ForeignData' which I suppose could be used to consruct the model but I am not sure.

**Other attempts:**
Web searches, visio help, browsing a python connection to the drawing, exporting drawing data to a database.

**Question:**
Can someone tell me how I can access my UML model info from a Visio diagram.  My preferred path would be to extract this info. into XML.

Comment: I did locate what appears to be binary data for the model with tags <Master><Icon>.  Is there anyway to get this out of Visio?

Comment: The <Master><Icon> binary data is common to UML shapes and basic shapes whereas a basic drawing does not include any <ForeignData>.  I need something that can read the <ForeignData> and output something usable.

Comment: Peeling an onion to no where. There is an undocumented ability to export something called an XMI file from the model. I did it but there is nothing recognizable from the actual drawing as far as I can tell so either I'm not doing it properly or I need to peel the onion further.  The command from VB is: Application.Addons("UML Background Add-on").Run("/CMD=400 /XMIFILE=""C:\path\file.xmi""") .  The link where I found this info is: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visio/archive/2009/05/11/follow-up-visio-2007-service-pack-2-and-visio-conference-2008.aspx